# Magento 2 - Can I have to create API, Interface & Resource Model for relational table

Tags: magento2, database, crud, interface

I am creating a module which have three tables let's say for example

```
table1
--------
id int(13) PRIMARY_KEY
title varchar(50)

table2
--------
id int(13) PRIMARY_KEY
title varchar(255)

table3 `relational_table`
--------
table1_id int(13) (foreign key of table1)
table2_id int(13) (foreign key of table2)
```

For table1 and table2 I have defined everything like Interface, API, Resource Model.

So my main concern is
**Should I have to create `PRIMARY_KEY` for table3 ?**
**Should I have to create Resource Model, Interface, API for table3**

If `YES` then how many things needed? and `NO` then how `crud` operation will be perform for maintaining relation?

I have referenced magento core module `module-tax` for `tax_rate` to `tax_rule` they have five tables and maintaining all relation.